# Consultar itens em histórico N:N

Tags: sql

Atualmente tenho um sistema básico de controle de ativos com a seguinte estrutura:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como voces podem observar, tenho uma tabela Muitos-Para-Muitos, no qual se chama `TB_HISTORICO_ATIVO`. Nela tem todo o historico em que o ativo passou, então tenho os seguintes status:

- Estoque
- Cliente
- Manutenção
- Queimado

O problema está ocorrendo na hora em que eu puxo o relatorio por **cliente**.

**Exemplo:**

Um ativo de número X estava no cliente na data de 01/01/2010, mas foi para a manutenção na data de 01/01/2012, isso implica que este ativo, não se encontra mais no cliente e sim na manutenção, mas, quando faço minha consulta, ele pega sempre o da data 01/01/2010, porque consta na tabela e tem o código do cliente.

**Meu select:**

```
SELECT
a.CODIGO as 'codigo_ativo',
a.NUMERO_ATIVO,
a.valor_compra,
a.obs as 'obs_ativo',

p.CODIGO as 'codigo_produto',
p.descricao as 'produto',

h.data_evento,
h.obs as 'obs_historico',

c.codigo as 'codigo_cliente',
c.descricao as 'cliente' 

from TB_HISTORICO_ATIVO H

left outer join TB_ATIVO a on H.ATIVO = a.CODIGO

left outer join TB_PRODUTO p on a.PRODUTO = p.CODIGO

left outer join TB_CLIENTE c on H.CLIENTE = c.CODIGO

where H.CLIENTE = 2
```

Comment: provavelmente sua consulta deve está retornando os dois registros, e você quer sempre o ultimo status seguindo a ordem cronologia. Certo?

Comment: Nao, ele está retornando apenas o registro que está amarrado com o cliente, mas na realidade, ele está retornando o status passado, neste caso, nao era pra retornar nada.

Comment: EU estou perdido nessa questão, rs, nao estou conseguindo resolver. Posso até resolver dentro da aplicação usando LINQ e tudo, mas quero deixar essa tarefa de filtrar os dados dentro da propria query.

Comment: Uma solução para simplificar os sqls pode ser criar uma coluna em TB_ATIVO data do último histórico (DT_ULTIMO_HISTORICO) e por *trigger* alimentar esta coluna , senão fazer sqls com subselect e max para obeter o historico mais recente

Comment: Interessante!... Essa solução de criar o campo e trabalhar com uma trigger. Mas, como ficaria o select com o MAX()? Tentei de N formas e nenhuma deu certo.

Comment: Show de bola @Motta, criei esse campo, migrei as informações, e neste select que passei acima, simplesmente implementei no filtro uma comparação por data de atualização! (y) Valeu.

Comment: com o 'max" seria algo assim ....   select * from historico where ativo = 123 data = (select max(data) from historico where ativo = 123)

Comment: Neste caso, eu nao teria o parametro do ativo, apenas do cliente.